# Was doppler effect for light proven experimentally?

Tags: waves, visible-light, photons, doppler-effect, redshift

If so, provide me with the data sources. From what I read, doppler for light is taken for granted. Or sometimes based on theoretical formulas. But if one wants to theorise, light is a mix of photons and there is no such thing as monochromatic photon. So let’s say blue shift is a real deal. Does it mean the white light will become a bit bluish if all photons in the mix become shorter? No, cause infrared photons in the mix will also shift and add missing red component to the palette again making the mix white. Same for the redshift when ultraviolet will become visible.
Thanks for the answers but still no actual answer for my question. Radar and satellites overhead are all about propagation of photons through air , were there actual experiments in vacuum or in outer space?

Comment: What about using a spectrometer on a source with discrete emission/absorption spikes?

Comment: You can just _purchase_ radar speed guns on Amazon, Measuring doppler shift is _how they work._

Comment: Where did you try to look for such data? What did you find? If what you found is not convincing enough, please explain, why?

Comment: Not to mention the red shift of galaxies, and the need to account for doppler shift in satellite communications.

Comment: Real white light does not consist of wavelengths from zero to infinite with same intensity for all wavelengths, as you seem to assume. Good thing too, or we would all be irradiated.

Comment: @DKNguyen i tried to explain that to him in the answer too lol

Comment: So, how fast a green car must move so that I saw it yellow? And also, does the distance to the observer matter?

Comment: Ham radio operators working ham satellites need to account for doppler shifts as the satellite passes overhead.

Comment: please learn the difference between perception of color and electromagnetic radiation ( and then get to photons) http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html

Comment: But we are. Skin cancer, you know…

Comment: @MrFramm There's sunburn, and then there's radiation sickness like at Chernobyl. Gamma rays are a form of light too. And if white light were the same intensity for all wavelengths you would be getting a healthy dose of gamma rays from every white light.

Comment: What do you think the Doppler shift variation from a binary star is due to?

Comment: @notovny pulsed Doppler doesn't really measure carrier signal Doppler. It measures the phase change with position in a mixed down signal...so the target could be stationary durning the entire time of the pulse interrogation (and moving during the gaps), and you'd get the same answer.

Comment: @annav You expect me to get PhD in physics to have the right to ask questions here ) Reminds me The Answerer (by Sheckley). I see this experiment like this: we have a laser or a maser and a receiver in vacuum. Then move the source and see if the receiver detects wavelengths change. Was it done? Or is that hard to do ?

Comment: @MrFramm this site is for questions and answers within the framework of mainstream physics and it is expected that a minimum knowledge of physics is required to get reasonable answers, not just the vocabulary of physics used randomly.

Comment: @annav You just repeated my words from previous post. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not a clear understanding of what doppler effect does and light/photons spectrum really is.

-Photons are quanta of a field with a given frequency, $\omega$.

-"Light" is a collection of a big number of such quanta doing stuff.

-Blueshift is the phenomenon which increase the frequency of your light/photons, namely the process $\omega_s \rightarrow \omega_s\sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}=\omega'$

-Redshift is the phenomenon which decrease the frequency of your light/photons, namely the process $\omega_s \rightarrow \omega_s\sqrt{\frac{1-v/c}{1+v/c}} = \omega'$

-White light is a collection of photons where you have all the components from the visible spectrum.

The thing you said about bluish/redish light is incorrect because it's not up to you to decide what light does.

You have a source that emits a bunch of photons in the range $[\omega_{min} , \omega_{max}]$ and if this source gets, let's say, blueshifted, you see photons in the range $[\omega_{min} + \delta, \omega_{max} + \delta]$,
where for blueshifts:

$\omega' - \omega = \delta = \sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}} - 1$

So you have that the total width of the spectrum remains constant, as you understood, but the starting point of this band is moved, so you cannot "add infrared photons" if your source doesn't emit such photons in the first place. Your spectrum is translated rigidly under doppler effect maintaining the width constant.

As an example of such effect you can search for a bunch of spectroscopy experiments with moving mirrors.

Comment: Ok, when you know what was emitted and what came, you can compare. How do you know something is redshifted when you only get the resulting light?

Comment: @MrFramm Cosmologists are comparing a bunch of different things and piecing it together to surmise the original wavelength of starlight. is based on studies of our own star and understanding of the physics of what should be happening in the star. The simplest one is that we know what the hydrogen spectral lines are so if we can find something in starlight that contains them, but they all happen to be shifted the same amount, then we can surmise it is hydrogen spectral lines that have been shifted.

Comment: @MrFramm usually in a lab you know both the spectrum of the resting source and then measure the moving one. If you refer to cosmology i should close this topic by accepting one answer and open a new one about how we know the frequencies emitted from astronomical sources, a comment will become too big

Comment: @LolloBoldo You didn’t answer my question. The answer is supposed to be: yes, and the link to the experiment. What you answered is my comment which says that I’m not convinced by the theories on the matter. But you give a theoretical proof. Theories never prove anything, they are good until proven wrong )